# Butler leaves whithout being fired in the Sims 3: Showtime

Tags: the-sims-3

Does somebody know why my butler keeps leaving without being fired? I've assigned a bed for him to sleep and I pay my bills on time. After a day or 2, he usually leaves without warning. When he has left though, I'm still able to rehire him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to maintain at least a 'Friendly' relation with your butler. If the relation bar ever becomes red, there are chances the butler will quit.